# Creation of RDF triples with "is a" relation - using WordNet?

Tags: rdf, wordnet

I want to create simple is-a kind of relation in rdf/xml format such that I can use the simple inferencing as

```
 a is b
 b is c 
 so a is c
```

but I need to use URIs for that. Can I use the URI of wordnet for that?

Comment: Question is little incomplete...What ontology library are you using?

Comment: Actually I am not that experienced in ontology creation.I don't know much about protege.I just want to use a simple option where I can use the wordnet entries

Comment: Wordnet has its own schema to establish relations among words likes synonyms,antonyms,hypernyms etc and you can accesss them by their API's.. if you wanna establish your own relation then you will have to define an ontology schema yourself.. You have to use protege or Apache Jena..

Comment: I think you may still need to clarify the meaning of your "is a" and "is" relationships.  "is" is not necessarily transitive.  However, the subclass relationship is, and it sounds like you want to say "A rdfs:subClassOf B", "B rdfs:subClassOf C" and infer that "A rdfs:subClassOf C".  That would work with an RDFS or OWL reasoner.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: There are RDF mappings for WordNet like http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn31/102086723-n or http://www.w3.org/TR/wordnet-rdf , but as pointed out in http://www.w3.org/TR/wordnet-rdf/#advanced (under "Using WordNet as a class hierarchy") there are some issues when simply using wordnet as a class hierarchy.

Comment: Actually I want to have "equivalence" kind of mapping between different words with the use of "wordnet relations".For example: forest is jungle ,wood is forest such that I can use this